# passing data from javaScript to MVC controller view ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

This is strange, I have no clue why this is not working, no matter what I do, I am always end up receiving null for the action method parameter. Why is that not working?

```
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="SaveDocument()"  />
```

```js
       function SaveDocument() {
            
         var data = "sss";

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Save",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (mydata) {
                    alert("Saved");
                },
                error: function(error)
                {
                    alert('failed');
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
          
        }
    
    </script>
```

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(string data)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify("sss")` resolves to `""sss""`
So this might be a problem, because this is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Look at @Jaimin Dave solution ... in your ajax call you have to pass `{ "data": "some string" }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created same test code in my local. i get null as you get. You can try with below code. it worked for me.

```
function SaveDocument() {          
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Save",
            type: "POST",               
            data: {"data" : "sss"},
            success: function (mydata) {
                alert("Saved");
            },
            error: function(error)
            {
                alert('failed');
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a js object(key value pair) to the `JSON.stringify` method, for sending the stringified version of data via your ajax call. The key/object property name should match with your action method parameter name.

The below should work.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ data:"some string"}),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

You might also want to consider a `return false;` in your js method so that the normal form submission won't happen.

Also since your server action method is returning `null`, you should not specify "json" as the "`dataType`" property value for your ajax call.  Just remove that line from your ajax call.

**Or** you can return some valid json data from your action method instead of `null`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(string data)
{
  return Json(data);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, so I replaced data part with what you have specified, still receiving null. Should I change anything else in the action method?

Comment: It should work. Just put a breakpoint in the method and inspect the value.I just verified it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the action parameter name to some other meaningful name. data is a reserved keyword in jQuery.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(string tempName)
{
  return Json(tempName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Javascript method
function postData(parsData)
    {
       var dataToSend = {  ParsData: parsData};

       var ReceivedData= JSON.stringify( dataToSend );
       $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("SetData")',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: ReceivedData
       }).done(function (response) 
       {
           console.log(response);

           document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response.resultHint;
           document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = response.resultAmount;
           document.getElementById("image").src = response.imageUrl;

        });
    }
//Javascript method Implementation
postData("Fuking code");

//C# Controller

public class ReceivedData
        {
            public string ParsData{ get; set; }
        }

        public class Result
        {
            public string resultHint { get; set; }
            public string resultAmount { get; set; }
            public string imageUrl { get; set; }
            public string decoded { get; set; }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SetData()
        {
            //var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           // ReceivedData decodedQR = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ReceivedData>(receivedData);
            // var dataObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(receivedData);
            // .. do something with data object 
            var jsonFromRequest = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            ReceivedData decodedQR = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReceivedData>(jsonFromRequest);



            Result result= new Result();

            result.resultHint = "Tem certeza que pretende permitir que o João Deposite o valor de ";
            result.decoded = decodedQR.ParsData;
            result.resultAmount = "200 MT";
            result.imageUrl = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300";

            return Json(result);
        }
```

`Credit to:` https://mestanzasoft.wordpress.com/2018/03/05/pass-data-from-asp-net-mvc-view-to-controller-with-ajax-and-json/